# How to check if the co-ordinates are within the bitmap or outside the bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

- I have a `Bitmap = x`;
- I have the co ordinates inside the BitMap `xCoOrdinate` ,
  `yCoOrdinate`

Dynamically this co ordinates changes, How to determine if `(xCoOrdinate,yCoOrdinate)` is within a bitmap or outside the bitmap

Comment: Is the bitmap inside image view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Rect and check if coordinates are in it .

```
val rect=Rect(imageView.left,imageView.top,imageView.right,imageView.bottom)

        if(rect.contains(xCoOrdinate.toInt(),yCoOrdinate.toInt())){
            //your x and y coordinates are in the bitmap region
        }
```